# TensorFlow Lite - Object Detection API YOLOv3

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I want to implement a TFLite Classifier based on YOLOv3 for Android. I'm a little noob with tensorflow lite object detection code...

I want to start from this implementation of [Object Detection TFLite](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/README.md). I tried to merge this code with this other implementation with [Yolo Classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowYoloDetector.java) but I had a lot of problems in adapting non-lite code with the lite version.

My question is: can i implement a classifier based on Yolov3 starting from TFLite examples?
I think that [TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java) is the class that i have to modify..is this correct? Or this API can be used to call a YoloClassifier Implementation written by myself?

I want to understand in details how I can use API to generate and apply my own classifier based on yolo. I have to implement a new class YoloClassifier.java that interfaces with the API.java file or i can only work on API to adapt new classifier?

Thanks to all in advance and I hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't convert the **complete** YOLOv3 model to a tensorflow lite model at the moment. This is because YOLOv3 extends on the original darknet backend used by YOLO and YOLOv2 by introducing some extra layers (also referred to as YOLOv3 head portion), which doesn't seem to be handled correctly (atleast in keras) in preparing the model for tflite conversion.

You can convert YOLOv3 to .tflite without the model's 'head' portion (See here: https://github.com/benjamintanweihao/YOLOv3), but then you will have to implement the missing parts in your Java code (as suggested here: https://github.com/wics1224/yolov3-android-tflite). Make sure you have the correct anchor box sizes if you do so. The second link would hopefully answer the second part of your question.

If you plan to keep things simple, your other options would be using SSD-mobilenet or yolov2-tiny for your application. They will give you a more real-time experience.

I am currently working on a similar project involving object detection in flutter/tflite so I'll keep you updated if I find anything new.

Edit:

In https://github.com/benjamintanweihao/YOLOv3, you'll need to change how you import libraries because **lite** library is moved out from **contrib** from tensorflow 1.14 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/zldrobit/onnx_tflite_yolov3, but the `NMS` is not in the TensorFlow compute graph. You have to implement your own `NMS` in your JAVA code.
Another issue with this repo is that it requires `ONNX` and PyTorch. If you are not familiar with them, it may cost you some time.